# LinkedIn Live Event API: Trouble with making call to test account (403)

Tags: linkedin-api, http-status-code-403

I'm a developer looking to use LinkedIn's API for [live scheduled events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/live-video/). I have my app approved and can make posts on behalf of coworker who meets the LinkedIn Live [access criteria](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a568503). But making random posts here is not ideal. I've had a search of Stack Overflow and it seems that there is an allowance for profiles to be used given that they are "Test Profiles" - the description is in the current [terms of use](https://www.linkedin.com/legal/l/api-terms-of-use) under section 2.3. But this is where the problem is. I've created an account and added is as 'Admin' to my admin portal, but my request is failing with `{"message":"No live video access.","status":403}`.

This is the request:

```
curl -i -X POST 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/liveVideos' -H 'X-RestLi-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" --data-raw

{
    "author": {
        "member": "urn:li:person:XXXXXXX"
    },
    "scheduledAt": 1699923600,
    "announcementImage": {
        "media": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "title": {
            "text": "Title of the image.",
            "inferredLocale": "en_US"
        }
    },
    "name": "Title of the scheduled live event"
}
```

Has anyone got an idea what the problem is, or have had luck doing this sort of thing?